# How to get Just plain text without using rich cards

Tags: c#, botframework

[image]

Below image is my QnA KB and here i am expecting output only Hello,how may i assist you? But when i am testing in emulator along with answer i am getting small image below to my answer as shown in first image highlighted.

[image] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqOQH.png)

Here is my below code:I am new to coding.Please tell if any changes required in below code.

```
 public class RootDialog : QnAMakerDialog        //IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            /* Wait until the first message is received from the conversation and call MessageReceviedAsync 
            *  to process that message. */
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
        {
            var reply1 = context.MakeMessage();
            var answer = result.Answers.First().Answer;
            Activity reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply();
            string[] qnaAnswerDate = answer.Split(';');
            int dataSize = qnaAnswerDate.Length;
            if (dataSize > 1 && dataSize <= 4)
            {
                var attachment = GetSelectedCard(answer);
                reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                await context.PostAsync(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
                await context.PostAsync(reply);
            }
        }
        private static Attachment GetSelectedCard(string answer)
        {
            int len = answer.Split(';').Length;
            switch (len)
            {
                case 4: return GetHeroCard(answer);
                default: //return GetHeroCard(answer);
                    return null;
            }
        }

        private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string answer)
        {
            string[] qnaAnswerData = answer.Split(';');
            string title = qnaAnswerData[0];
            string description = qnaAnswerData[1];
            string url = qnaAnswerData[2];
            string imageURL = qnaAnswerData[3];
            HeroCard card = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = title,
                Subtitle = description,
            };
            card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                              {
                                  new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl,"Learn More" ,value:url)
                              };
            card.Images = new List<CardImage>
                              {
                                  new CardImage(url=imageURL)
                              };
            return card.ToAttachment();
        }
        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            /* When MessageReceivedAsync is called, it's passed an IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>. To get the message,
             *  await the result. */
            var message = await result;
            // var qnaAuthKey = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAAuthKey");
            var qnaAuthKey = GetSetting("QnAAuthKey");
            // var qnaKBId = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId");
            // var endpointHostName = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAEndpointHostName");
            var qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
            var endpointHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"];

            // QnA Subscription Key and KnowledgeBase Id null verification
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaAuthKey) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaKBId))
            {
                // Forward to the appropriate Dialog based on whether the endpoint hostname is present
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointHostName))
                    await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
                else
                    await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.");
            }

        }

        private async Task AfterAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            // wait for the next user message
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public static string GetSetting(string key)
        {
            var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && key == "QnAAuthKey")
            {
                value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnASubscriptionKey"]; // QnASubscriptionKey for backward compatibility with QnAMaker (Preview)
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    // Dialog for QnAMaker Preview service
    [Serializable]
    public class BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog : QnAMakerDialog
    {
        public BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5)))
        { }
    }

    // Dialog for QnAMaker GA service
    [Serializable]
    public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
    {

        public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5, 1, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"])))
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please only post the minimal code.

Comment: Sure.Minimized the code.

Comment: We can't give an answer with this code as we don't know what do you have in your QnA KB, and we don't even know what are your `BasicQnAMakerDialog`  and `BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog`. Based on the code you provided, it looks like things are not really clear for you about how QnAMaker dialogs are used

Comment: Hi Nicolas, i am new to coding,based upon your suggestions i edited the question and please let me know any additional details required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> getting small image below to my answer

If you send a empty **HeroCard** like below to the user, which would be rendered like a blank image.

[image]

> I am new to coding.Please tell if any changes required in below code.

In your code, we can find that you forward message to ***BasicQnAMakerDialog*** for QnAMaker GA service, so I assume that you are using QnAMaker GA service and use GA QnAMaker service credentials to initiate your QnAMakerDialog to response user query. You can refer to the following sample code to modify your project.

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        /* Wait until the first message is received from the conversation and call MessageReceviedAsync 
        *  to process that message. */
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        /* When MessageReceivedAsync is called, it's passed an IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>. To get the message,
            *  await the result. */
        var message = await result;
        // var qnaAuthKey = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAAuthKey");
        var qnaAuthKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"];
        var qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
        var endpointHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"];

        // QnA Subscription Key and KnowledgeBase Id null verification
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaAuthKey) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaKBId))
        {
            await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.");
        }

    }

    private async Task AfterAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        // wait for the next user message
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

}

// Dialog for QnAMaker GA service
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5, 1, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"])))
    {
    }

    protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
    {
        var answer = result.Answers.First().Answer;
        Activity reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply();
        string[] qnaAnswerDate = answer.Split(';');
        int dataSize = qnaAnswerDate.Length;

        if (dataSize > 1 && dataSize <= 4)
        {
            var attachment = GetSelectedCard(answer);
            reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync(answer);
        }
    }

    private async Task AfterBasicQnAMakeAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private static Attachment GetSelectedCard(string answer)
    {
        int len = answer.Split(';').Length;
        switch (len)
        {
            case 4: return GetHeroCard(answer);
            default: //return GetHeroCard(answer);
                return null;
        }
    }

    private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string answer)
    {
        string[] qnaAnswerData = answer.Split(';');
        string title = qnaAnswerData[0];
        string description = qnaAnswerData[1];
        string url = qnaAnswerData[2];
        string imageURL = qnaAnswerData[3];
        HeroCard card = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = title,
            Subtitle = description,
        };
        card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                            {
                                new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl,"Learn More" ,value:url)
                            };
        card.Images = new List<CardImage>
                            {
                                new CardImage(url=imageURL)
                            };
        return card.ToAttachment();
    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's working fine after following above code.